# PRISM Scoped EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

For a PRISM Project with many similar Shells we need to fire the Same `Event` via the `EventAggregator`. I don't want to filter the Events once they are already subscribed.

**Is it possible in PRISM to create a local or scoped `EventAggregator` once per Module/Shell?**

Comment: Consider to create specified Event in each module.

Comment: The Problem is that I want to create Widgets which can be used in Every Module. So they need to subscribe on the same event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible right off the bat. 
The only solution I can think of is to register your `EventAggregator` in a child `UnityContainer` when you create your `regions`.

Another solution is to create specifiek event classes for every module.